# Authentication failure with curl in PHP ( openssh connexion OK )

Tags: php, curl, ftp, sftp, php-curl

I am trying to connect via php curl on an SFTP destination, with key authentication.

I manage to connect outside of curl, with openSSH: ( it work )

```
sftp -i myPrivateKey sftp://myusername@destination.com
```

however, I cannot reproduce this connection in curl, I have an authentication failure error. how is that possible?

```
    $dest = 'sftp://myusername@mydestination:22';

    $curlHandler = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_URL, $dest);
    curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
    curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE, mypublickey);
    curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE,myprivatekey);

    $resp = curl_exec($curlHandler);
```

log:

```
* SSH public key authentication failed: Callback returned error
* Failure connecting to agent
* Authentication failure
* Closing connection 0
```

I am sure of the validity of the keys, I checked the fingerprints with the remote server, and I manage to connect outside of php-curl.

I also checked that my keys were in restricted access and accessible

Comment: the first thing you can do is to validate the return of curl_setopt(), which returns bool(false) on error, does any of your curl_setopt's return false?

Comment: after testing each curl_setopt, each of these field returns me a valid true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it turns out that ubuntu LTS 14 uses the libgcrypt utility, which creates SSH keys with private keys starting with" ----BEGIN OPENSSH ---" and in the case of SFTP, we need a .pem starting with "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", so I converted my private key, and it worked

```
ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -m pem -p
```